# Use Google maps as Outlook add-in for Office 365 pro-plus

Tags: office365, google-maps, outlook-addin

I just got Office 365 pro-plus, and saw that for Outlook emails, there's an add-in available for Bing Maps that will show you a map of any addresses typed in the email.  Is there a way to use Google maps rather than Bing?  It looks like you can change the registry to allow that in other versions of Office, but I'm not sure it'll work with Office 365.

Comment: "but I'm not sure it'll work with Office 365." What happened when you tried?

Answer (score 1):

In regedit, browse to:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Options\General
```

Right-click in the right pane and click on New / String Value. For the string name, enter:

```
MapScriptURL
```

Double-click on the `MapScriptURL` key to open it. Enter this for the data value.

```
https://maps.google.com/?q=<0s>+<1s>+<2s>+<3s>+<4s>
```

It's working great but the credit goes to https://www.brucebnews.com/

Answer (score 0):

The apps are actually web based.  You'll need a different add-in to use Google maps, Currently I only see one listed in the store and it's not free
https://store.office.com/maps-for-outlook-WA104380098.aspx?assetid=WA104380098&sourcecorrid=51b2a6a9-919a-4211-bee6-f2449f70b1f5&searchapppos=0

Answer (score -1):

This works but only from within outlook contacts.. if the address is within the email body and you want to view it in google, that's where it will still map it using bing maps.. Have not been able to fix that. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: It appears you are asking how to resolve a problem you have.  Asking questions within an answer submitted to a question will remain unanswered. If you have a question, [edit] your answer so it specifically addresses the author's question, and submit your own question.